# Select All CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint-2007

I am having a problem, I am trying to make a link for a acsx file. Basically checkboxes get dynamically generated through pulling information out of a sharepoint list. These are HTML boxes. Ive tried using the runat=server on the boxes, ive tried using javascript to select the by creating a form that just contains the checkboxes but neither of those will select any checkboxes. Anyone have any idea on how I can select all the checkboxes on a page.

Thanks

Comment: no votes, 8 questions, and 1 accepted answer?  sorry, hopefully someone will help you.

Comment: what are you talking about? @jondavidjohn

Comment: I'm glad my comment made an impression, keep it up ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without really understanding, what you need to do, this JavaScript code will select all checkboxes within a container with the id `boxes` (i.e. `<div id="boxes">...</div>`):

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementById( 'boxes' ).getElementsByTagName( 'input' );
for ( var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++ )
{
    if ( checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox' )
    {
        checkboxes[i].chcked = true;
    }
}
```

(This is a solution without jquery & other frameworks, but of course if you are already using one, just use their built-in method for doing this)

Answer (score 1):

something like this should do the trick:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").attr('checked','checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to select all checkboxes in a page and set them that way.